# Maximize Page Value Syncing between Multiple Users in App Maker?

Tags: google-app-maker

I would like to know how the best way and how to ensure multiple users using an App Maker app see the same data when using the App simultaneously.

For example, if two users are on a ContactEdit page, for example, and they are editing the same Contact item details. If the datasource is set to autosave (i.e. not manual save mode), is the expected behavior that if one user updates Contact Name (input/edit field for the Contact item's name), that the other users viewing the same ContactEdit page for that item will also have its Contact Name field updated with the new value?

Or is it perhaps only bindings that might "push" changes to another user? For example, if there is a label widget at the top displaying the Full Name of the contact, which is bound to the Contact Name field, will that update for all users or just the current user?

In my testing (in preview mode), it seems that the data only updates once I refresh the page manually (not sure if this is a preview mode limitation or not). It seems that unless the datasource is reloaded (and even when I added a Datasource Reload onAttach of the page it wasn't always consistently updating and I would need to navigate away first and then back), changes are not "pushed" to other users, is that correct? Is there a way to push changes to all users immediately?

Thanks for your time and consideration!

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to resemble something like in the image below, I strongly suggest you to use Firebase.

[image]

I recommend you to read the documentation to [**get started**](https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup) with Firebase. Otherwise, it is an extremely appealing feature for appmaker native datasources. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks so much for the suggestion and video demonstration!

Is Firebase meant to replace Google Cloud SQL or somehow work on top of it? If it replaces it, are there any disadvantages in doing so? I was reading about the Firebase database and it seems to be structured quite differently than a relational database, just wondering if I'd be giving something else up for this feature.